# Extract usernames from text file

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I want to find all the usernames in the text file below using VBScript. We receive such a file daily with different usernames. There might be more than one username in each text file. I want to extract those usernames into the following format:

```
sutedan / chavaji / samdave
```

Data.txt:

```
application;account;entitlement;owner;action;reason;request_no;creation_date;review_name;sent_to;entitlement_description
36475-5;sutedan;gmrsk_TC_BIZ_CRE|gmrsk_TC_BIZ_EM|revoke account;Off-boarding;2d71c99-1688-4d09-b132-9029bf681084< ;29.07.2015 21:44:47;revoke account;
"For the New business line CRE ""|Emerging Markets Client business profile""|Emerging Markets Prop business profile""|Global Equity Derivatives Client business profile""
|Global Equity Derivatives Prop business profile""|Fixed Income Client business profile""|Global Credit Trading Client business profile""|Prime Brokerage business profile""|
PPSN Client business profile""|Global Rates Client business profile""|Global Rates Deutsche Securities Inc. business profile""|Global Rates Prop business profile""
|RMBS Client business profile""|RMBS Prop business profile""|Valuations Services Group business""|Tradecapture: Region: Frankfurt""|TradeCapture rights for the Sydney Region
 ""|Read only profile for GT support staff wishing to view trades only for a particular business/region combination in order to remediate systemic or specific trade problems"
application;account;entitlement;owner;action;reason;request_no;creation_date;review_name;sent_to;entitlement_description
36475-5;chavaji;gmrsk_TC_BIZ_CRE|gmrsk_TC_BIZ_EM|revoke account;Off-boarding;2d71c99-1688-4d09-b132-9010bf681084< ;29.07.2015 21:44:47;revoke account;
"For the New business line CRE ""|Emerging Markets Client business profile""|Emerging Markets Prop business profile""|Global Equity Derivatives Client business profile""
|Global Equity Derivatives Prop business profile""|Fixed Income Client business profile""|Global Credit Trading Client business profile""|Prime Brokerage business profile""|
PPSN Client business profile""|Global Rates Client business profile""|Global Rates Deutsche Securities Inc. business profile""|Global Rates Prop business profile""
|RMBS Client business profile""|RMBS Prop business profile""|Valuations Services Group business""|Tradecapture: Region: Frankfurt""|TradeCapture rights for the Sydney Region
 ""|Read only profile for GT support staff wishing to view trades only for a particular business/region combination in order to remediate systemic or specific trade problems"
application;account;entitlement;owner;action;reason;request_no;creation_date;review_name;sent_to;entitlement_description
36475-2;samdave;gmrsk_TC_BIZ_CRE|gmrsk_TC_BIZ_EM|revoke account;Off-boarding;2d71c99-1688-4d09-b132-9029bf691084< ;29.07.2015 21:44:47;revoke account;
"For the New business line CRE ""|Emerging Markets Client business profile""|Emerging Markets Prop business profile""|Global Equity Derivatives Client business profile""
|Global Equity Derivatives Prop business profile""|Fixed Income Client business profile""|Global Credit Trading Client business profile""|Prime Brokerage business profile""|
PPSN Client business profile""|Global Rates Client business profile""|Global Rates Deutsche Securities Inc. business profile""|Global Rates Prop business profile""
|RMBS Client business profile""|RMBS Prop business profile""|Valuations Services Group business""|Tradecapture: Region: Frankfurt""|TradeCapture rights for the Sydney Region
 ""|Read only profile for GT support staff wishing to view trades only for a particular business/region combination in order to remediate systemic or specific trade problems"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me.  My code assumes username comes at the same spot for each new section of information.  I use the field account as my starting point to reference where it is coming.  It works with the sample data at least.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, fOpenFile, fReadFile, data, x, userList, dataLineStart
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fOpenFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\My\Drive\Path\Data.txt")
fReadFile = fOpenFile.ReadAll
fOpenFile.close
Set fOpenFile = Nothing

data = Split(fReadFile, ";")
userList = ""
dataLineStart = 0

for each x in data
    if x = "account" then dataLineStart = 1
    if dataLineStart = 11 then userList = userList & x & " / "
    dataLineStart = dataLineStart + 1
next

userList = left(userList, len(userList)- 3)
Wscript.Echo(userList)
```

Comment: Not working. Why you have used ** .can you please explain ?

Comment: But there is no ** character at starting and ending of username

Comment: Well somehow when I copied your text file, I got that ** character string.  I'll modify my code in an edit shortly.

Comment: Code edited above.  This answer will make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Will the usernames always be preceded by a `#####-#` style number? If so, you could probably just match the field after that pattern occurs. It wouldn't match the GUID found later on, since the only possible `#####-#` pattern within the GUID wouldn't be followed by a semicolon.

```
' Using the file path from your comment...
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strText = .OpenTextFile("C:\Users\chavaji\Documents\Data.txt").ReadAll
End With

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\d{5}-\d;([^;]+);"
    .Global = True
    Set mc = .Execute(strText)
End With

ReDim a(mc.Count - 1)
For i = 0 To mc.Count - 1
    a(i) = mc(i).SubMatches(0)
Next

WScript.Echo Join(a, " / ")
```

The more information you can supply for the pattern, the better, though. For example, if the next field always begins `gmrsk`, then that could improve this regex significantly.

Comment: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set strText = fso.OpenTextFil("C:\Users\chavaji\Documents\Data.txt",1)
  print  strText.ReadAll
  
  With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\d{5}-\d;([^;]+);"
    .Global = True
    Set mc = .Execute(strText)
End With

ReDim a(mc.Count - 1)
For i = 0 To mc.Count - 1
    a(i) = mc(i).SubMatches(0)
Next

WScript.Echo Join(a, " / ")   getting error type mismatch : 'Execute'  set mc = .Execute(strText)

Comment: There are two different  ids 36475-2; 36475-5; from there user names get starts.

Comment: Anyone can help on this

Comment: Edit your question and include your current script. It looks like `strText` is a `TextStream` object in your code above, so you'll need to use `Set mc = .Execute(strText.ReadAll)`.

Comment: getting error Input past end of file

Line (8): "Set mc = .Execute(strText.ReadAll)".

Comment: @Ajinkya - You're getting this because it looks like you're already reading the whole file earlier when you do `print strText.ReadAll`. So the whole file has been read and you can't read it again later. Instead, read the file contents into a variable. I've updated the answer to show you how to do this.